# How do I extract the function from a piecewise defined function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, piecewise, mupad

I'm using the new Matlab piecewise function (https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/piecewise.html ) introduced in the Symbolic Math Toolbox `R2016b` to define a function, and I'm trying to extract the function. Specifically my code looks something like:

```
syms x;
y = piecewise(x>1,3*x^2,0);
```

I'd like to be able to extract just the `3*x^2` from `y` without the condition.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use children:

```
syms x;
y = piecewise(x>1,3*x^2,0);
childs=children(y)
myfunc=childs(1)
```